# Django - Show a lightbox gallery in the template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have these models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CarImage(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(to=Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_upload = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", blank=True, null=True)
```

From my DetailView to the template I am passing the `Car` instance's data and also the `CarImage` instances belonging to the specific `Car`.

How do I create a simple, but responsive lightbox gallery of images from `CarImage` instances if I shall **not** use JavaScript frameworks like Vue, React or anything else?

I am looking to get a gallery like these ones:
https://photoswipe.com/ or https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/ - I was not able to get them running either because of some weird JavaScript issues, or, because they require some license to be purchased.

Thank you